# Pandas : Dataframe Merge Error with two columns match

Tags: pandas, join, dataframe, merge

I have 2 dataframes that look very closely to the one below (there are extra columns that however shouldn't affect the result):

**Edit**: Added extra variable as requested.  The - sign means missing data

**dataframe1**

```
ProductID      Date           Booked Rate

10             01/01/2017     10.0
10             02/01/2017     0.3
10             03/01/2017      70.4
20             01/01/2017     100.0
20             02/01/2017      70.0
20             03/01/2017     0.1
-              04/01/2017      0.5
```

**dataframe2**

```
ProductID      Date           Actual Rate

10             01/01/2017     11.0
10             02/01/2017     12.3
10             03/01/2017      75.4
20             01/01/2017     110.0
20             02/01/2017     80.0
30             03/01/2017     10.1
-              04/01/2017     0.7
```

Ideally the result should be **dataframe 3:**

```
 ProductID      Date          Booked Rate   Actual Rate

 10            01/01/2017     10.0         11.0
 10            02/01/2017     0.3          12.3
 10            03/01/2017      70.4         75.4
 20            01/01/2017     100.0        110.0
 20            02/01/2017     70.0         80.0
 20            03/01/2017     0.1          -
 -             04/01/2017     0.5          -
```

When I do the merge on my real dataset, using the following code :

```
df3 = pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2, how="left", left_on=["ProductID", "Date"], right_on=["ProductID", "Date"])
```

I get the wrong result as numbers from the extra columns (ommited for clarity) are sometimes doubled/tripled.

**Edit:** **This seems to be because it matches the empty ProductID fields from dataframe1 with the empty productIDs from dataframe2. I would need to ommit this.**

What I really need, is a simple merge where the actual rate from dataframe2 is added as a new column when it finds a match for productId and Date in dataframe1. Any extra item from dataframe2 should be excluded, and no matches in dataframe1 should be excluded.

I also tried, right, inner, outer, merges.

It seems to always warp the result in the same exact way (doubling and tripling certain line items).

Comment: Are malformed dates intentional?

Comment: Does `-` mean it's missing or equal to the string `'-'`?

Answer (score 0):

use `pd.merge`

```
dataframe1.merge(dataframe2, on=['ProductID', 'Date'], how='left')

   ProductID        Date  Booked Rate  Actual Rate
0         10  01/01/2017         10.0         11.0
1         10  02/01/2017          0.3         12.3
2         10  03/01/2017         70.4         75.4
3         20  01/01/2017        100.0        110.0
4         20  02/01/2017         70.0         80.0
5         20  03/01/2017          0.1          NaN
```

---

If you have `NaN` in your `ProductID` column

```
d1 = dataframe1.dropna(subset=['ProductID'])
d2 = dataframe2.dropna(subset=['ProductID'])

print(d1.merge(d2, on=['ProductID', 'Date'], how='left'))

  ProductID        Date  Booked Rate  Actual Rate
0        10  01/01/2017         10.0         11.0
1        10  02/01/2017          0.3         12.3
2        10  03/01/2017         70.4         75.4
3        20  01/01/2017        100.0        110.0
4        20  02/01/2017         70.0         80.0
5        20  03/01/2017          0.1          NaN
```

Comment: Hi @pirSquared I tried that method already as well, one of my extra columns (Impressions), passes from 493763131 to 561349264 after that type of merge as well. I think there's some kind of variable I am not taking into consideration

Comment: This is a case in point why showing us what you've tried and an example that reproduces a problem is important.  As it is, you asked a simple question and received an answer to that question.  After the answer has been given, you bring up that there are other things to consider.  I appreciate that asking a good and complete question is sometimes difficult.  But you can take from this experience and learn how to better articulate what you need in the future.   Hopefully that is helpful, because that is how I meant it.  Edit your question with the relevant information.

Comment: Hi @pRSquared, you are totally correct. I will amend the information, I think I have found the problem, and that is, that when there is missing information for the Product ID, from both dataframes, it will consider it as a match

Comment: Hi @pRsquared, just finished editing the data now, sorry it took a bit, but currently on phone! Thank you for your help. I think I might need a function  now that I look at it to keep the  missing productId lines from dataframe1